# Html font size defaulting 36

Tags: c#, html

I am working on a c# script that writes emails in Outlook in html code. While I input  message  the font being sent is size 36. Why is this?

```
"<html><b><center><font color = red , font size=48> ATTENTION </font></b></break></center></html>"
```

That is the starting point of the string. Every part of the html is working correctly but the size. obviously with no periods.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?  If you want, put some CSS styling in and pick whatever font you want

Comment: What is the string you're setting the body to?

Comment: added the code I am trying to edit into the original post.

Comment: Is your HTML being generated as it is presented in the question?  Why does every tag have a period, and no quotes around the attributes?

Comment: The <font> tag is deprecated too.

Comment: sorry Amy, there is "" around the whole thing and there is no periods. It kept formatting the code so I added the periods to display it.

Comment: @DustinWillingham To format code, prefix it with 4 spaces like I did in the edit.  Please edit your HTML so it matches what you actually have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting e-mail body HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871445/formatting-e-mail-body-html)

Comment: That HTML still is **not valid**.  HTML attributes require double quotes around the values.  I'm confident that this is actually what you have, since it matches your previous question exactly.  And `</break>` is not an HTML tag that I am familiar with.

Comment: Thank You the exact code I have is now in the code box.

Comment: I can appreciate that you needed your previous question answered, but duplicating it isn't the solution.  Editing your other question will move it to the home page of the site and increase its visibility.  You need to make your HTML valid, and since you are producing this HTML using C# code, which is not present in this question but *is* present in the other question, as a duplicate, this one will not help you solve your problem.  You need to fix your C# code, to fix your HTML.  So edit and focus on the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `"<div style='color:red;text-align:center;font-size:48pt'> ATTENTION </div>"`

Comment: Shouldn't that be a `<span/>` and not a `<div/>`?

Comment: @Flydog57 I tried span but it didn't center the text in Chrome. I'm not sure how Outlook will show it

Comment: this helped me a lot, Thank You!

Comment: @C.M.since this is the head of the email and I want to add text bellow this, how would I go about formatting that?

Comment: @DustinWillingham Put the text inside either a new <div> or <span> with style attributes set as needed.